# MOSFET Leakage current

Tags: led, operational-amplifier, mosfet, leakage-current

I tried this circuit with a power LED, without gate resistor and with \$R_s=4.7\Omega\$:

[image]

I discovered that when the Vin+ is at GND, there is still some leakage current which keeps the LED ON very dimly.

Edit: the implemented final circuit is this one
[image]

I discovered that when should be OFF, the gate voltage is slightly below the \$V_{\text{GS}}\$, which is around 3 or 4V. I'm supposing that this behaviour is the amplification of the offset of the LM324 which is able to open slightly the MOS. But it is not generating a sufficient voltage drop on the sense resistor, and it is comparable to the offset and as a consequence the correction from the op amp stops when the drop on the sense resistor is comparable to the offset at its inputs. Keeping everything in this equilibrium with the LED *almost* OFF.

How should I proceed to guarantee a better OFF status? I thought of using a MOSFET with a lower threshold, and/or better op amp with a lower offset. But I don't think that this guarantees a priori a complete OFF status.

Comment: Can you measure the output offset voltage of your opamp (i.e. with its inputs grounded)?

Comment: By the way, since you've managed to confuse Kevin, is it so hard to post a schematic that reflects the actual circuit you're using? I understand you've probably got that one from the interwebz, but you can just fix it up in MS Paint  (or equivalent) alone if it's too much work to redo it from scratch in a schematic editor.

Comment: And since the schematic came up: if you'd have simulated this circuit (which would have been a freebie after doing the schematic in an actual schematic editor), you'd have probably found out what the problem is... TI's SPICE model of LM324 is pretty good, including the offsets we're talking about (at some typical values).

Comment: Schematic editing made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly it is because of the offset voltage of the LM324 which can be quite a few millivolts in either direction.

It would act as if you have a few millivolts at the input even when there isn't.

If for example the opamp has 7mV offset it will drive the MOSFET to produce 7mV across Rs - about 1.5mA with a 4.7 ohm sense resistor. If the offset had been the opposite polarity then it would have turned off the MOSFET altogether.

Changing the threshold of the MOSFET won't help as it is inside the negative feedback loop and the opamp will just change its output to keep the commanded current flowing through Rs.

One way to avoid the problem is to force a small current through Rs even when the MOSFET is off. You need at least 1.5mA (the current caused by the worst case offset) - this would require a 5.6K resistor from the source of the MOSFET to the positive terminal of the power supply (assuming an 8.5V supply).  This will guarantee that the MOSFET will be off even with up to 7mV of offset in the opamp.

Also that circuit as designed may be unstable as the 10K resistor you have feeding the MOSFET gate is rather high - it will interact with the input capacitance of the MOSFET and give a delay in the negative feedback loop (also called a Pole).  I would change Rg to 100 ohm. From your opening sentence I gather the schematic is not correct but bear this in mind if you do use a resistor feeding the gate.

Edit - corrected the calculations for 7mV offset and 4.7 ohm sense resistor as pointed out by Andy Aka.

Comment: Rs is 4.7 ohms so theoretical current flow assuming a 5mV offset is 1mA.

Comment: Max input offset for TI's LM324 at 25C is 7mA according to datasheet, by the way. (LM324A has max 3mA though.)

Comment: Also, he says (in text) he's not actually using a gate resistor.

Comment: Ah, I missed that.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff you have right. But, by considering the bright side, in this way I read an important consideration from Kevin about the gate, without excluding a correct interpretation. I will edit, as soon as I can.
And so, Kevin, why you suggest 100Ohm instead of  nothing?

Comment: You're right Rg is not necessary, and could be replace with a short circuit - I often include one though to allow access to the opamp output directly for test purposes, or if you need to provide some feedback loop compensation (although there I would need a resistor in series with the inverting input as well to provide an injection point).

Comment: I tried to verify what you said. In this way the MOSFET will allways put "strongly" in OFF state if the supply voltage increases when Vin+ is at GND, since tries to output a negative voltage. And since the 8.5V is not regulated, I can also provide this voltage from wherever I want, if needed. Nice.

Comment: In general driving a MOSFET from an opam output is not a good idea because opamps have fairly limited current they can dish at the MOSFET's gate. People think that because the MOSFET draws virtually no power/current through the gate (while on or off), it's okay to put a low current driver on its gate... ignoring the current requirements during transients/switching. That's a newbie mistake. I suspect the 10k series resistor was an ad-hoc solution for avoiding damage to the opamp's output. The LM324 is not overcurrent protected.

Comment: Case in point: https://youtu.be/lmnp1ot_QnI (and that's using sc-protected opam.)

Comment: Ok, nice. I was aware of the transient, but I didn't think of a practical implementation for this. 
What happens to the stability if I put a 10K pull down do GND on the MOSFET gate? That was my first naive idea before yours advice.

Comment: Actually it has a short circuit protection. The protection is not present when shorting to Vcc (and destructive for Vcc>15V).
Moreover, with 10K gate resistor, the circuits oscillates even more (before compensation). Just limiting the maximum current to 30mA maybe will be enough (Vcc/30mA=500Ohm)

Comment: @RespawnedFluff An edit: I tried with 1K gate resistor (on breadboard and antenna-wires) and the oscillation seems to be to lower entity.

Comment: We miss you ...RespawnedFluff